# Persistent Import Error for NLTK Corpus Twitter_samples

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, nltk, spyder

I am using this script to try to import the twitter_samples from the `nltk` package for python. I am currently working in python 2.7 in an Anaconda Environment.
I am using Spyder to run the code.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('twitter_samples')
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples
print twitter_samples.fileid()
```

And I am getting this as a return when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Person\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Person\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Ben/Anaconda3/attemptNLTK_download.py", line 9, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples
ImportError: cannot import name twitter_samples
```

but when I import movie_reviews it works fine.

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
```

I don't really have any leads on why this isn't working. I added an environmental variable to my system for NLTK_DATA as C:\nltk_data as suggested, but that didn't fix it. It is living in the default location(C:\nltk_data).

Maybe there is a way to "import" the corpora directly without using import... The data is there on my C drive and I can see it, I just cannot access it via the import functionality.

I'm trying to use the data to train a classifier for positive/negative statements/tweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples` is correct, according to the NLTK's [twitter HOWTO](http://www.nltk.org/howto/twitter.html#corpus_reader), so the most likely reason for the import error is that your version of the nltk is out of date.

The nltk's twitter package is quite new; it was added in September 2015 with version 3.0.5, but "improved" in various ways since then.  Right now the nltk is at version 3.2, <s>but the current Anaconda distribution comes with nltk 3.1.</s> Which one do you have? You can check the nltk version by printing out `nltk.__version__`.

To update to the latest version distributed by Anaconda, start an Anaconda command prompt and run this command:

```
% conda update nltk
```

Anaconda updated to the current version of the nltk within days of its release, so I would expect them to continue to do so with future versions unless some compatibility issue arises.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response and the reasons behind it. You were correct. I had 3.0.3 .  However, conda installed nltk 3.2, It's probably just a recent update.   Thanks for the correct diagnosis.

Comment: Just after I wrote this answer I found out that NLTK 3.2 had been released that same day! Good to know that Anaconda tracks the current version within a few days, then.