# LookupError for "twitter_samples"

Tags: python, jupyter, nltk

Could someone please help me with the following error? I am using the codes below in Ananoda Jupyter on a macbook,

```
import nltk                                # Python library for NLP
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples    # sample Twitter dataset from NLTK
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt            # library for visualization
import random                              # pseudo-random number generator

# downloads sample twitter dataset.
nltk.download('twitter_samples', download_dir='/Users/Dropbox/Coursera/NLP')

# select the set of positive and negative tweets
all_positive_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('positive_tweets.json')
all_negative_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('negative_tweets.json')
```

but always getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py in __load(self)
     79             except LookupError as e:
---> 80                 try: root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))
     81                 except LookupError: raise e

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py in find(resource_name, paths)
    674     resource_not_found = '\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' % (sep, msg, sep)
--> 675     raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
    676 

LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource twitter_samples not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('twitter_samples')
  
  Searched in:
    - '/Users/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/opt/anaconda3/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/opt/anaconda3/share/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d293b64f6340> in <module>
      1 # select the set of positive and negative tweets
----> 2 all_positive_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('positive_tweets.json')
      3 #all_negative_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('negative_tweets.json')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    114             raise AttributeError("LazyCorpusLoader object has no attribute '__bases__'")
    115 
--> 116         self.__load()
    117         # This looks circular, but its not, since __load() changes our
    118         # __class__ to something new:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py in __load(self)
     79             except LookupError as e:
     80                 try: root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))
---> 81                 except LookupError: raise e
     82 
     83         # Load the corpus.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py in __load(self)
     76         else:
     77             try:
---> 78                 root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, self.__name))
     79             except LookupError as e:
     80                 try: root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py in find(resource_name, paths)
    673     sep = '*' * 70
    674     resource_not_found = '\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' % (sep, msg, sep)
--> 675     raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
    676 
    677 

LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource twitter_samples not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('twitter_samples')
  
  Searched in:
    - '/Users/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/opt/anaconda3/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/opt/anaconda3/share/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

I've checked out a similar post ([Persistent Import Error for NLTK Corpus Twitter_samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740529/persistent-import-error-for-nltk-corpus-twitter-samples)) and updated the nltk package accordingly. The issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running these commands from a python command line shell

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

You will get a popup , choose the required items and download them

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried those codes from a python command line shell by downloading the required items. However, the same errors remain. (Initially the default path denied permission for the download, so I changed the path to the same folder as my Jupyter script and completed the download.)

Comment: The comment from stackover flow says twitter sample module is found in ntlk version 3.2,  Can you check with version using !pip freeze